# IE 125% zoom renders a extra border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

As you can see, the color blocks are rendering a kind of extra border. This problem appears when I zoon to 125% in IE. Safari, chrome are rendering well.

What can I do to fix this issue? (see orange and green blocks)

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: Zooming is known to cause weird rendering issues in most browsers, and there's not a lot you can do about it. The best answer is just to avoid doing it.

Comment: Yes, something I was already thinking. Zoom is more an option to size the text on a page right?